# Proving the inequality: dim(W1 + W2) = dim(W1) + dim(W2) − dim(W1 ∩ W2)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

My idea is that the vector space W1∩W2 is a subspace of both W1 and W2, and so it has a basis B which is a linearly independent subset of both W1 and W2. 
We know that we can always take a linearly independent subset of a vector space and complete it to a basis of that space, and so do that with B for W1 to obtain B∪S1, and also do that for W2 to obtain B∪S2.

Where do I go from here, and how can I use it to get the W1+W2 side?

Comment: This is an equality, not an inequality.

Comment: All that remains is to prove that $B\cup S_1 \cup S_2$ is a basis for $W_1+W_2$!